# How can I select items where there exists a reference between each item and all items in a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects called `Keywords`, each with an Id.

In my database, I have a table of `Forms` and a table of `KeywordReferences`.

Each `KeywordReference` has a `FormId` and a `KeywordId`.

What I need to do is create a query that gets all `Forms` where there exists a `KeywordReference` between that form's `Id` and *all* `Keywords` in the original list.

So basically I have some `Forms` like:

```
Form:
Name: Test1
Id: 1

Form:
Name: Test2
Id: 2
```

Then several `KeywordReferences`

```
KeywordReference:
FormId: 1
KeywordId: 1

KeywordReference: 
FormId: 1
KeywordId: 2

KeywordReference:
FormId: 2
KeywordId: 2
```

And then I have a list of `Keywords`:

```
Keyword: 
Name: Primary
Id: 1

Keyword: 
Name: Secondary
Id: 2
```

The query should return `Test1`, because there exists a `KeywordReference` to `Test1` for all `Keyword` items in the list.

It should not return `Test2` because that form only matches one of the items in `Keywords`.

How can I write such a query?

**EDIT** This is an example of a query that gets all forms where *any* match occurs between the keywords in the list and a given form, but I need to write a query where *all* matches occur:

```
    var forms = from form in db.Forms    
                join reference in db.KeywordReferences on form.Id equals reference.FormId 
                join filter in filters on reference.DepartmentKeywordId equals filter.Id    reference in the filter
                select form;
```

Comment: you are telling us specifications which have nothing to do with the issue and or problem, meaning; `What is your question or Where is the question`

Comment: The question is how can I write such a query?  If you would like I can copy and paste a query that does not do this, but I don't think that would help :)

Comment: are you familiar with SQL..? if not then I would do some reading on key words like `SELECT Query, JOINS, etc..` this is not a code factory site once again please try something on your own and show us first what you have tired..

Comment: _"I need to write a query where all matches occur"_ -- have you _tried_ to write such a query? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows your attempt to solve the problem, along with a clear, detailed explanation of what that code does, and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: Ok how about this for the question: what type of join is that? what is that type of query called?  I'm trying to figure this out and I've been searching around but when you don't know what to search for it's difficult to find any answers.  Do you actually know the answer to my question or did you just come here to harass me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *all* the keywords to be present, so test `keywords.All`.

Within that test for all, you need there to be a matching relevant keyword-reference, so test `keywordReferences.Any`:

```
from f in forms
where keywords.All(
  kw => keywordReferences.Any(
    kr => kr.KeywordId == kw.Id && kr.FormId == f.Id))
select f;
```